# magento i need to display category images in my home page

Tags: magento-1.9

Here is my code it is displaying categories with sub categories and working fine, my requirement is to show category images, now i am displaying static images

```
     <ul>
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId =Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getThumbnail() : $currentCategoryId='';
        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
        ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><?php echo $_category->getName();?></a>
                <?php $categoryChildren = $_category->getChildren(); ?>
                <?php  if($categoryChildren->count()) : ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($categoryChildren as $_categoryChild) : ?>
                            <?php $_categoryChildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryChild->getId());?>
                            <?php $categoryGrandchildren=$_categoryChild->getChildren(); ?>

                            <li>

                                <?php
                                   $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                    echo '&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryChildModel->getUrl() . '">' . ' &nbsp; <img src="'.$this->getskinurl().'/images/menu_ic1.png" align="absmiddle" /> &nbsp;' .  $_categoryChild->getName() . '</a>';

                                ?>                                                           
                            </li>
                            <?php if($categoryGrandchildren->count()) : ?>
                                <?php foreach($categoryGrandchildren as $_categoryGrandchild) : ?>
                                    <?php $_categoryGrandchildModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryGrandchild->getId());?>
                                    <li>
                                        <?php
                                            $currentCategoryId===$_categoryChild->getId() ? $bold="style=\"font-weight:bold\"" : $bold='';
                                            echo '&emsp;&emsp;' . '<a href="' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getUrl() . '"' . $bold . '>' .  $_categoryGrandchild->getName() . '(' . $_categoryGrandchildModel->getProductCount() . ')</a>';
                                        ?>

                                    </li>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php if($category->getThumbnail()): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $category->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'. $category->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt=""  />
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT:**

Here is full script I used on one of my projects - create file subcategory_listing.phtml in template/catalog/navigation

```
<?php
/*
* List Sub catgories template
*/
?>

<?php
    $object = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
    $categoyrId = 2;
    $actualCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoyrId);
    $subCategories = explode(',', $actualCategory->getChildren()); ?>

    <div class="sub-cat-list">
    <h2>CATEGORIES</h2>
    <ul>
    <?php $i; foreach ($subCategories as $subCategoryId): $i++; ?>
        <?php 
        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);
        if ($category->getIsActive() ): 
        ?>
        <li class="catItem">

            <?php if($category->getThumbnail()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $category->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'. $category->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt=""  /></a>
            <?php endif; ?> 
            <div class="bottom">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $category->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></a></h3>

            <?php // show subs ?>
            <?php $newSubCategories = explode(',', $category->getChildren()); ?>
            <ul> 
                <?php foreach ($newSubCategories as $newSubCategoryId): ?>
                <?php $newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($newSubCategoryId); ?>
                    <li class="subCat">
                    <a href="<?php echo $newCategory->getURL(); ?>" class="categoryLink" title="<?php echo $newCategory->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $newCategory->getName(); ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <a class="viewAll" href="<?php echo $category->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $category->getName(); ?>"><span>Check All Categories</span></a>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?> 
    </ul>
    </div>
```

The script calls the main category thumbnail image and get all subs links, sure you can edit to call also the sub thumbnails.

Comment: thank you for answer,it is not working for me

Comment: why it is not working? what is the error?

Comment: First this script will call category thumbnail, and you need to change $category-> to  $_categoryGrandchild-> I'll edit the answer with full script

Comment: yes its working but it is displaying only main category images, if main category images are not there then it is not displaying any thing. if you have idea then tell me otherwise i will work on that, Thanks for quick response.

Comment: add this after <li class="subCat"> :::: <?php if($newCategory->getThumbnail()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $newCategory->getURL(); ?>" title="<?php echo $newCategory->getName(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'. $newCategory->getThumbnail(); ?>" alt=""  /></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

Comment: Glade to help can you please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: Removed `!empty()` @ `if(!empty($category->getChildren()))`. 
>   This causes a fatal error PHP5.5 because return is always false
>   instead just use `if($category->getChildren())`

Nice work!

Add an if statement to the submenu ul so it only shows when there are subcategories.
`

```
<?php if(!empty($category->getChildren())):?>
                <ul> 
                    <?php foreach ($newSubCategories as $newSubCategoryId): ?>
                    <?php $newCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($newSubCategoryId); ?>
                        <li class="subCat">
                            <a href="<?php echo $newCategory->getURL(); ?>" class="categoryLink" title="<?php echo $newCategory->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $newCategory->getName(); ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

`